# Magnetic buzzer causes interference in the circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I have the following circuit:

[image]

The models in the circuit are:

- Buzzer - SMT-0931-S-R
- Transistor - ZXTN2018F
- Diode - BAT54WS

When the buzzer turns on (beeps every about 500ms) I'm getting serious noise on the 5v voltage - It drops from 5v to about 3v while the PWM is on.

What could cause such an effect? Am I pulling too much current?

What should I change in the design?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the 5V coming from, what current can it handle?

Comment: A MAX8815A, which holds up to 1A on 5V

Comment: Maybe it's having trouble because the load is relatively low and it uses it's skip mode. Can you try to drive the SKIPB pin of the regulator high and see if that improves anything?

Comment: Tried that just now, but the noise is still there (Good idea though!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the spec on the device - it has a terminal resistance of 17 Ω to 23 Ω. At 17 Ω and 5V you'll be drawing 294 mA yet the device is typically expected to run at 80 mA (max).

Put a resistor in series with it and read the data sheet. If you still have problems with your power supply after putting the resistor in series then it's your power supply more than likely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a right base resistor value for Ib to get 80mA Ic.